# How to extract image name using python regexp?

Tags: python, regex

so i want to extract the images name from the path , to use them as labels further in a classification Task.
this is the pasth:

[PosixPath('/content/drive/My Drive/Logo/adidas10.jpg'),

PosixPath('/content/drive/My Drive/Logo/adidas11.jpg'),

PosixPath('/content/drive/My Drive/Logo/adidas13.jpg'),

.
  .
  .] and it goes on for 600 images .

so what i want to get is the brand name , like in this case adidas.

here's the RegEx expression i used :

```
r’([\w\s.-]).[jpg]’
```

but , what i get after checking the images label is this:

```
 print(data.classes)

 ['L']
```

any Suggestions ? , thanks.

Comment: please read up what `[...]` mean

Comment: and `.` for that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make use of a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html) which will one of the listed characters. So your pattern `([\w\s.-]).[jpg]` will capture in a group matching one of `[\w\s.-]`, then match match any char except a newline due to the dot `.` and then match one of `[jpg]`.

For your example data, that will give you a capturing group for `L` and a match for `og` as well as a capturing group for `0`, `1`,`3` and a match for `.j`

If you want to get the brand name like *adidas* from your examples as you state in your question, you could use a capturing group.

```
/([^/]*[^/\d])\d*\.jpg
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mmwtNC/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oQrrCA)

That will match

- `/` Match literally
- `(` Capturing group (This will contain the brand name)

  - `[^/]*` Match not a `/` 0+ times not a `/` using a negated [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
  - `[^/\d]` Match not a `/` or a digit
- `)` Close group
- `\d*` Match 0+ times a digit
- `\.jpg` Match .jpg

Comment: That's exactly the expression that I ended up using after tweaking the previous one that has been given to me .                                                   Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 3):

`([\w\s.-])` (any of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, whitespaces, literal `.`, literal `-`) is capturing the `L` in `Logo` because it follows:

- `.`: any single character; `o` in this case
- `[jpg]`: any of `j`, `p`, `g`; `g` here

You need:

```
/([^/]+)\.jpg$
```

Now the only captured group will contain the image name.

- `/` matches literal `/`
- `([^/]+)` matches one or more characters that are not `/` -- the file name
- `\.jpg` matches `.jpg` at the end (`$`)

Answer (score 3):

A great resource to try your regex out is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

You try to group the file ending together using square braces `[]` which creates a selection of either of the three characters `j`, `p` or `g`. The dot is not escaped and thus - in regex syntax - is any character. Since you never add any multipliers (like `+` for 1 or more characters, `*` for 0 or more characters or `?` for an optional character), you only match a few letters in total.

If you want to read a bit more about all regex operators, modifiers and similar concepts, [I recommend reading the documentation of python's `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

You can either rewrite the regular expression to something like this (extract the first group in order to retrieve the filename) or use the fact that there is a path processing library in the `os` package:

```
^.*\/([^\/]+\.jpg).*$
```

[You can see this regex in action here.](https://regex101.com/r/02cQa4/2)

Since you seem to already have path objects available, you could however just extract the [basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) of the path, which in your case will be the filename:

```
from os.path import basename
a = '/content/drive/My Drive/Logo/adidas10.jpg'
filename = basename(a)
```

`filename` would now be `adidas10.jpg`

Comment: Thank U guys , now i see the errors I made , it's been super helpful and instructive .

Comment: I am glad that we could help. I added another link to a good place to start learning more about the syntax of regular expressions in the answer. I hope it helps you on your journey to become a regex master :-)